# XF86MonBrightnessUp/XF86MonBrightnessDown special keys not working

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard-shortcuts, i3, backlight

I'm trying to enable some multimedia keys, and the ones for volume do work. `F5` and `F6`, the ones for increasing/decreasing do not work, I do not know why.
When I run in the terminal:

```
xbacklight +10
```

I can see the working effect. When I try my binded special keys (which are set to `~/.config/i3/config`):

```
# Sreen brightness controls
bindsym XF86MonBrightnessUp exec xbacklight -inc 20 # increase screen brightness
bindsym XF86MonBrightnessDown exec xbacklight -dec 20 # decrease screen brightness
```

Obviously, the media keys must be combined with the `fn` key. However, I don't see the effect. Any solutions?

Comment: Are you sure the key symbols are `XF86MonBrightness(Up|Down)`? As in: "Did you check with `xev`?" While these key symbols do exist, there are also `XF86KbdBrightness(Up|Down)`.

Comment: I have this problem also, supposedly you are meant to discover the keys using `xmodmap -pke` and then somehow apply these in the i3 config.

Answer (score 10):

**Edit**: You must have `acpi` installed on your machine for these to work :)

**Edit 2**: This code increments/decrements the brightness values by 1, but some models will have values that range in the thousands, so modify the change accordingly.

This is an old question, but an answer may help out others. I ran into an issue upon a fresh installation of `i3wm` on my laptop where, for whatever reason, my `XF86MonBrightnessUp/Down` keys weren't being registered (I checked with `xev`). What I ended up doing is creating `acpi` actions and events which corresponded to the keys being pressed.

The following are the actions/events I defined in `/etc/acpi/actions` and `/etc/acpi/events`, respectively:

#### Actions

*/etc/acpi/actions/bl-down.sh*

```
#!/bin/sh

bl_device=/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
echo $(($(cat $bl_device)-1)) | sudo tee $bl_device
```

*/etc/acpi/actions/bl-up.sh*

```
#!/bin/sh

bl_device=/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
echo $(($(cat $bl_device)+1)) | sudo tee $bl_device
```

#### Events

*/etc/acpi/events/bl-down*

```
event=video/brightnessdown BRTDN 00000087 00000000
action=/etc/acpi/actions/bl-down.sh
```

*/etc/acpi/events/bl-up*

```
event=video/brightnessup BRTUP 00000086 00000000
action=/etc/acpi/actions/bl-up.sh
```

You can verify your brightnessup/down acpi event codes by using `acpi_listen` in your terminal and then pressing the relevant key combination (e.g., for me, it's Fn + Down Arrow for brightness down).

Finally, don't forget to restart `acpid` with `sudo /etc/init.d/acpid reload`

**Note:** Your backlight device may be defined in a different location than `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0` - that's just where mine happened to be. Do some poking around.

Comment: this helped! If anyone else hits this and are running a setup with SELinux, you'll will need to allow the given scripts via audit2allow or another tool.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue with arch on my dell xps. Installing the `xf86-video-intel` package fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

To complete the great answer from Try431, the action configuration that worked for my Lenovo G580 was the one below.

Note:

- events were the same as Try431
- I'm also running i3wm
- had to add `chmod +x` to the sh files so they could be executed
- my card was intel, so the `bl_device` path was different
- the increment/decrement was too small. I changed it to steps of 100.

*/etc/acpi/actions/bl-down.sh*

```
#!/bin/sh
bl_device=/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
echo $(($(cat $bl_device)-100)) | sudo tee $bl_device
```

*/etc/acpi/events/bl-up*

```
#!/bin/sh
bl_device=/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
echo $(($(cat $bl_device)+100)) | sudo tee $bl_device
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend `light`.

```
bindsym XF86MonBrightnessUp exec --no-startup-id light -A 5
bindsym XF86MonBrightnessDown exec --no-startup-id light -U 5
```

https://github.com/haikarainen/light

Answer (score 0):

`xbacklight` wasn't working for me either, but the solution needn't be so complicated!

I installed the `brightnessctl` package using apt. https://github.com/Hummer12007/brightnessctl

I have the following in my *config* file:

```
# Sreen brightness controls
bindsym XF86MonBrightnessUp exec brightnessctl -d "intel_backlight" set +8%
bindsym XF86MonBrightnessDown exec brightnessctl -d "intel_backlight" set 8%-
```

You may need to replace "intel_backlight" with something else.
Use `brightnessctl -l` to find the appropriate ID.