# Control screen brightness in i3

Tags: i3, brightness

I would like to control the screen brightness in **i3**, in Intel laptops that come with *Fn* keys for the purpose. These keys function with any other DE.

First making sure devices available are Intel:

```
$ ls -l /sys/class/backlight/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 juin  24 18:26 intel_backlight -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-eDP-1/intel_backlight
```

[In another forum](https://faq.i3wm.org/question/3445/change-brightness-in-i3-macbook-pro/index.html) the programme `xbacklight` is suggested as means to control brightness in **i3**. However it fails in the laptops I tried so far:

```
$ xbacklight -inc 10
No outputs have backlight property
```

Is there any other way to control brightness in **i3**?

Comment: maybe try `xrandr`? also check https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Backlight#xbacklight

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To change your screen brightness, you can use `xrandr`.

In order to do this, you can do:

```
xrandr -q | grep ' connected' | head -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f1
```

That will return all the connected monitors (like `LVDS-1` or `DVI-D-0` for instance).

Now, to change the screen brightness do the command (replace the `DVI-D-0` by the precedent command output):

```
xrandr --output DVI-D-0 --brightness 0.7
```

For instance, this command sets the brightness to 70%.

I hope it will help !

Comment: Note that it will only **emulate** screen brightness.

Comment: To elaborate, changing the "brightness" with `xrandr` doesn't actually adjust the backlight brightness, it just adjusts the colours sent to the pixels. This makes the colours look awful at lower "brightnesses".

Answer (score 30):

[`brightnessctl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/brightnessctl.1.html) can be used to set the *actual* device brightness.

Comment: This is by far the easiest and most straightforward way I found. I am using i3 on Fedora (RedHat kernel) if it helps anyone. Although I think you should include a working snippet for guys in hurry :D

Comment: `brightnessctl set 20%-` down and `brightnessctl set +20%` up (position of the `-` and `+` matter)

Answer (score 14):

My solution. It is tested on Ubuntu 20.04.

1. `sudo apt install light`
2. `sudo chmod +s /usr/bin/light`
3. Add to i3 config:

   `bindsym XF86MonBrightnessUp exec --no-startup-id light -A 1 # increase screen brightness`
   `bindsym XF86MonBrightnessDown exec --no-startup-id light -U 1 # decrease screen brightness`

Comment: This also works on Debian, though the chmod is unnecessary since light uses udev rules now (though I did have to reboot for the rules to take effect).

Comment: The chmod command was necessary on Ubuntu 21.10 running i3

Comment: important to note that **light** is an orphaned project and the github repo is now archived. see: https://github.com/haikarainen/light

Answer (score 5):

Copying from an old answer of mine to a question: [XF86MonBrightnessUp/XF86MonBrightnessDown special keys not working](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/322814/xf86monbrightnessup-xf86monbrightnessdown-special-keys-not-working/427572#427572)

---

**Edit**: As noted below, you must have `acpi` installed on your machine for these to work :)

**Edit 2**: This code increments/decrements the brightness values by 1, but some models will have values that range in the thousands, so modify the change accordingly.

This is an old question, but an answer may help out others. I ran into an issue upon a fresh installation of `i3wm` on my laptop where, for whatever reason, my `XF86MonBrightnessUp/Down` keys weren't being registered (I checked with `xev`). What I ended up doing is creating `acpi` actions and events which corresponded to the keys being pressed.

The following are the actions/events I defined in `/etc/acpi/actions` and `/etc/acpi/events`, respectively:

#### Actions

*/etc/acpi/actions/bl-down.sh*

```
#!/bin/sh

bl_device=/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
echo $(($(cat $bl_device)-1)) | sudo tee $bl_device
```

*/etc/acpi/actions/bl-up.sh*

```
#!/bin/sh

bl_device=/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
echo $(($(cat $bl_device)+1)) | sudo tee $bl_device
```

#### Events

*/etc/acpi/events/bl-down*

```
event=video/brightnessdown BRTDN 00000087 00000000
action=/etc/acpi/actions/bl-down.sh
```

*/etc/acpi/events/bl-up*

```
event=video/brightnessup BRTUP 00000086 00000000
action=/etc/acpi/actions/bl-up.sh
```

You can verify your brightnessup/down acpi event codes by using `acpi_listen` in your terminal and then pressing the relevant key combination (e.g., for me, it's Fn + Down Arrow for brightness down).

Finally, don't forget to restart `acpid` with `sudo /etc/init.d/acpid reload`

**Note:** Your backlight device may be defined in a different location than `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0` - that's just where mine happened to be. Do some poking around.

Comment: This was the answer that helped me! It'd be nice to mention, that you need `acpi` installed at the top :)

Comment: Range for brightness on my machine is 0-24000, so $(( old_value - 1 )) doesn't quite do the job. Perhaps something like $(( old_value < step ? 0 : old_value - step )) makes more sense with appropriate step. Besides modern acpid reloads config on SIGHUP.

Answer (score 3):

Using [brightnessctl](https://github.com/Hummer12007/brightnessctl) from @leafmeal's answer, I've added these keybindings to my `.config/i3/config`:

```
bindsym XF86MonBrightnessDown exec brightnessctl s 5%-
bindsym XF86MonBrightnessUp exec brightnessctl s +5%
```

Note: when you install brightnessctl, you might need to restart in order for it to work without sudo.

Comment: 'brightnessctrl' also works perfectly well on Arch with Sway, if anyone is interested.

Answer (score 2):

There's 2 `xbacklight`. In Archlinux (might be same in your distro), one comes in the package `xorg-xbacklight` sourced from https://xorg.freedesktop.org/ and the other is in the package `acpilight` sourced from https://gitlab.com/wavexx/acpilight. If one doesn't work, perhaps the other will.

The description for `xorg-xbacklight` says:

> RandR-based backlight control application

And from the `acpilight` link:

> On some modern laptops "XRandR" might lack the ability to set the display brightness. This capability was moved/unified to the kernel's ACPI interface, via /sys/class/backlight/. "acpilight" provides a drop-in replacement for the xbacklight command that uses the ACPI interface instead of "XRandR"

So, that might be the reason why your `xbacklight` doesn't work.

Comment: This is what I needed :)
When searching for `acpilight` I have found this in the Arch wiki:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Backlight
"xbacklight returns : No outputs have backlight property. Depending on the video card installed, sometimes xbacklight from xorg-xbacklight returns the message "No outputs have backlight property". Installing acpilight provides an alternative xbacklight that may work as expected."

Answer (score 2):

my current solution:

1. get the default display (ex DVI-0)

   `xrandr -q | grep " connected " | cut -d' ' -f1 | head -n 1`
2. add the following to `~/.config/i3/config` replacing DVI-0 with whatever your display is

```
bindsym XF86MonBrightnessUp exec --no-startup-id bash -c 'b=$(xrandr --verbose | grep -i brightness | head -n 1 | cut -d" " -f2) && b2=$(echo -e "import math\nf = lambda x: (1 - 1/(1+math.exp(4*x-2)))\nprint(\\\"%.2f\\\" % f(0.1+$b))" | python) && xrandr --output DVI-0 --brightness $b2'

bindsym XF86MonBrightnessDown exec --no-startup-id bash -c 'b=$(xrandr --verbose | grep -i brightness | head -n 1 | cut -d" " -f2) && b2=$(echo -e "import math\nf = lambda x: (1 - 1/(1+math.exp(4*x-2)))\nprint(\\\"%.2f\\\" % f(-0.1+$b))" | python) && xrandr --output DVI-0 --brightness $b2'
```

Comment: That works,  my laptop's default fn keys to control brightness are now functional, however, I noticed that the lower bound using this is much lower than what I use to get in gnome and the upper bound seems to be lower than the maximum I use to get in gnome too probably. I use arch btw and have started using i3 for less than a week so don't know much about that. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Here is bash script solution based on `xrandr`: First create a file to store the current brightness value using `echo 1.o > brightness.txt`. Now the following bash script can be used:

```
#!/bin/bash

BRIGHT=`cat brightness.txt`

if [ "$1" = '+' ]; then
    NEWBRIGHT=$(echo "$BRIGHT + 0.05" | bc)
    if [ "$(echo "$NEWBRIGHT > 1.0" | bc)" -eq 1 ]; then
        NEWBRIGHT='1.0'
    fi
elif [ "$1" = '-' ]; then
    NEWBRIGHT=$(echo "$BRIGHT - 0.05" | bc)
    if [ "$(echo "$NEWBRIGHT < 0.0" | bc)" -eq 1 ]; then
        NEWBRIGHT='0.0'
    fi
fi
```

Suppose the above script is called `brightness.sh` then it can be used as:

```
.\brightness.sh + #to increase brightness
.\brightness.sh - #to decrease brightness
```

And since you use `i3` you can bind keys to these commands. For example you can add these lines to to your `i3-config`:

```
# change brightness of screen
mode "controls" {
        # These bindings trigger as soon as you enter the control mode
        bindsym j exec "~/Scripts/brightness.sh -"
        bindsym k exec "~/Scripts/brightness.sh +"
        # back to normal: Enter or Escape
        bindsym Return mode "default"
        bindsym space mode "default"
}

bindsym $mod+shift+semicolon mode "controls"
```

Further add these line to your `i3-config`  to start at the last-used brightness value:

```
exec "~/Scripts/brightness.sh -"
exec "~/Scripts/brightness.sh +"
```

Answer (score 0):

The inspired_Blue answer is a good answer for using xrandr but it's inclomplete, I suggest to add theese lines at the end of the bash script to make it work:

```
echo $NEWBRIGHT > brightness.txt
xrandr --output LVDS-1 --brightness $NEWBRIGHT
```

be careful to check your display name with

`xrandr -q | grep ' connected' | head -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f1`

as shown by Jae Beojkkoch.
In my case the name is LVDS-1.

The first line rewrites the txt file using the new value of brightness, the second one is used to set the brightness using xrandr.

Answer (score 0):

Install `ddcutil` .You might need to install `i2c-tools` first and run

```
 sudo modprobe i2c-dev
```

And add your username to i2c group:

```
sudo usermod -G i2c -a your_user
```

You can run:

```
sudo ddcutil capabilities
```

to see what can be controlled

And to increase/decrease backlight you can do:

```
sudo ddcutil setvcp 10 + 10
sudo ddcutil setvcp 10 - 10
```

respectively.

For more info on `ddcutil` I suggest you check the documentation at:
https://www.ddcutil.com/command_setvcp/

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler way to do this in Arch/Ubuntu systems is by making `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` with contents as follows:

```bash
Section "Device"
        Identifier  "card0"
        Driver      "intel"
        Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
        BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

then add these lines in your `i3/config`

```bash
bindsym XF86MonBrightnessUp exec xbacklight -inc 10
bindsym XF86MonBrightnessDown exec xbacklight -dec 10
```

> This will make `i3` use your *keyboard brightness keys* to control the brightness of your screen and you can even turn it all the way to 0 to make your screen black, and the brightness this solution gives at 100% is also quite good which I was unable to get through some other solutions.

This solution is inspired from [Wayne Werner's](https://askubuntu.com/a/1060160) answer.